# Adding .java library to an Android project

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I have a library I want to add to my Android Application. But the problem is that the library is separated into `.java` files. Now I have tried to add a module to do the job but it does not work. My problem is I do not know how to add a bunch of `.java` files to my Android project to use throughout my app. I am new to Android dev and I have looked around but cannot find a clear explanation of how to add my type of library to an Android project.[image]

Comment: Many libraries are a collection of .java files; Are they all part of the same library project? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Yes they are all apart of the same library and I am using Android Studio.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils could it be the way I am importing them?

Comment: Sorry, when I noticed you're using Android Studio I had to step back. I'm not thrilled with using it, but I'll check it out and see if I can figure it out. Perhaps add your procedure to the post, it might be something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of problems in the screenshot that you just posted above.

1) It seems that you're not telling Gradle (and therefore Android Studio) that you have Java files that need to be compiled. You can fix that by adding this to the build.gradle of the TMDB-Lib module:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'libs'
    }
  }
}
```

and then adding the module to your `settings.gradle`.

2) It seems that the `Tmdb` classes don't have a package (i.e. their first line isn't a package declaration) so the right way to import them into your Java code is by using just their class name:

```
import TmdbApi;
```

instead of:

```
import TMDB-lib.libs.TmdbApi;
```